# Error handling and interpolation in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, error-handling, interpolation, data-processing

I'm currently working on a MATLAB script which spots errors from motion sensors where the data 'flips' hemisphere and records the inverse of what it should be. In addition to this there is a transitional period where the sensor continues to record values during this 'flipping' process.

An example can be seen below (the x-axis is time in samples and y is the sensor's distance from the sensor in inches):

[image]

My current progress is as follows:

[image]

The data errors have been suppressed but are still not consistent with the rest of the data set. Could anyone suggest a method to improve?

My code is as follows:

```
%Create counter variable
n = 1;

%Find length of the matrix under test
size = length(mTest);
intVals = zeros(size,1);

for n = 1:size

    %Round all of the values recorded to the nearest integer (inch)
    intVals(n,1) = round(mTest(n,1)); 

end

%Find the mode of the integers to have a reference point against the errors
ref = mode(intVals);

%Create a sample to put the new `fixed` data into
mFix1 = zeros(size,1);

for n = 1:size

    checkVal = mTest(n,1);

    %If the raw value is not within an inch either side of the reference 
    %point check for complete wrapping by inverting the data.
    if checkVal < (ref-1)
        checkVal = -checkVal;
    end

    if checkVal > (ref+1);
        checkVal = -checkVal;
    end

    %If the data is still outside of the range of acceptable values create
    %an estimate based upon the last 3 samples
    if checkVal < (ref-1) && checkVal > (ref+1)
        m(1,1) = mFix1(n-3,1);
        m(2,1) = mFix1(n-2,1);
        m(3,1) = mFix1(n-1,1);
        checkVal = mean(m);       
    end

    %Output the data after error checking
    mFix1(n,1) = checkVal;

end
```

Comment: What do you know about the correct values when you get those strange readings? What are the requirements? Just a smooth curve?

Comment: I know for this particular case the correct values are mostly around the ~4.8 to ~5.2 inches mark and in correct samples the difference is only ~0.01 to ~0.05. Unfortunately the real troublesome values (i.e. transitional - not yet completely inverted) do not give any hint to where they fall in this range so I need to estimate...

Comment: And yes, the required output would be smoothed values in between correct points. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried a median filter?

If you can find a good window width, it should probably work a little better then the moving average you are performing.

For example:

```
Avg([1 100 1]) = 34;
Median([1 100 1) = 1;
```

Matlab medfilt1